# How to undefine a define at commandline using GCC

Tags: gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

How do I at compile time undefine a compiler macro using GCC? I tried some compile arguments to GCC, like [-D](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1), but I can't get to see the "not defined" message.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define MYDEF


int main(){

#ifdef MYDEF
  std::cout << "defined\n";
#else
  std::cout << "not defined\n";
#endif

}
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the [-U](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-U) option with GCC, but it won't undefine a macro defined in your source code. As far as I know, there isn't any way to do that.

Comment: Yeah, `-U` only works with macros also defined on the command line. You can't undefine a macro defined in code from the CL.

Comment: @MarcW The requirement would not even make any sense, because the (un)definitions on the command line are understood as preceding the program text. So it's like wanting an `#undef` at line 16 to neutralize a macro at line 42.

Comment: @MarcW Also, `-U` works not only with macros defined on the command line, but on predefined macros. This is very useful. I'm dealing with a case compiling code on Termux where the builtin definition of `__ANDROID_API__`  as `24` is failing to reveal functions that are in fact declared in headers and available for linkage. To fix this, I'm putting a `-U` for this symbol, followed by a `-D` to a higher value.  Without the `-U`, you get diagnostics that the command line is redefining a macro differently.

Answer (score 21):

You should wrap the `MYDEF` definition in a preprocessor macro, the presence of which (defined on the command line) would then prevent MYDEF from being defined.  It is a bit convoluted to be sure, but you can then control the build in the way you want from the command line (or [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Makefile)).  Example:

```cpp
#ifndef DONT_DEFINE_MYDEF
#define MYDEF
#endif
```

Then from the command line when you don't want MYDEF:

`gcc -DDONT_DEFINE_MYDEF ...`

Answer (score 13):

The [-U](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-U) option seemed like what you could have needed... but then again you can't override a definition contained in your source code without resorting to more preprocessor directives.

Answer (score 4):

You can resort to filtering source code and give this back to GCC for compilation, like this pseudocode:

```
grep -v "define MYDEF" yourFile.c | gcc -o yourFile.o -xc -
```

Answer (score 1):

The code use case is not right. As I see it, you have hard coded `#define` in the file. If the compiler initially assumes `MYDEF` undefined, it will define it once it starts processing the file.

You should remove the line `#define MYDEF`. And I hope your test case will work, if you pass `MYDEF` to [-D](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1) and [-U](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-U).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility that doesn't completely cover your use case but which I found to be helpful in my case.

If your `MYDEF` were #defined in a separate header file #included from the .c file you could force the definition of the #include guard macro with the `-D` option (thus preventing the `MYDEF` #definition) then either actively #define (still with the `-D` option) `MYDEF` to something else or just leave it undefined.

It is clear that anything else defined in the header file would also be missing but this was for me a solution to forcedly undefine a macro without changing the third-party code.

Comment: Please note my use case: I'm not doing this for production code - there you should properly have the third-party code cleaned - but for unit tests to improve the branch coverage by suppressing third-party code I cannot influence but which is taken account by the code coverage tool as these are macros. Hence the tweak.