# Undefine defined preprocessor variable using Makefiles

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

In a C file, *file.c*, I have

```
#define STUFF
```

I want a Makefile so that I can prevent `STUFF` from being defined in *file.c*. I want to control the compilation using only the Makefile (and I do not want to comment out the line in the *.c* file directly).

GCC has the [-D](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1) option. I can do

```
 gcc -D STUFF file.c -o output
```

for defining `STUFF`; but I cannot *undefine* `STUFF` invoking GCC or using the Makefile (with GCC invoked in the Makefile of course).

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you modify the .c file at all? Is it required that STUFF be defined if there is no definition on the command line?

Comment: There is a corresponding command to undefine things: `-U`.  However, this only undefines values which are already defined at that point, either built-in or from the command line:  it doesn't take precedence over things that will later be defined in various files.  So if you use `-DFOO -UFOO` then `FOO` is not defined.  But you can't undefine something that's `#define`d in a source file from the command line.  It would be nice if `-U` worked like an override and ensured that all attempts to `#define` that macro in the source would be ignored.  But it doesn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to undefine a define at commandline using gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978155/how-to-undefine-a-define-at-commandline-using-gcc)

Answer (score 6):

```
#define STUFF

#ifdef REMOVE_STUFF
#undef STUFF
#endif
```

Then compile with `gcc -DREMOVE_STUFF ...`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change file.c, you can't do this without changing the source  file.
e.g. make it:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_STUFF
#define STUFF
#endif
```

And have your makefile add the `-DENABLE_STUFF` flag

Comment: But in this case STUFF will not be defined for a compile with no command line definition, which seems to be a requirement (the question is a little unclear on that).

Answer (score 0):

Better option:

```
#ifndef ENABLE_STUFF
#define ENABLE_STUFF 1
#endif

#if ENABLE_STUFF
#define STUFF
#endif
```

Using `#if` instead of `#ifdef` allows you to set the macro several times in the command line, with latter values overriding the previous ones:

```bash
gcc -DENABLE_STUFF -DENABLE_STUFF=0
#    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
#    same as -DENABLE_STUFF=1
```

This helps if the first `-DENABLE_STUFF` comes e.g. from some variable in the build system, and you want to override it in specific circumstances without touching that variable.